# Estimator variance problem

Tags: variance, parameter-estimation

[The equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzpa1.png)

Hi all,

I am preparing for an upcoming exam and I just don't seem to get this specific equation where I try to derive the variance of an estimator analytically.

I know the answer is var = sigma^2/(N*4) , however, I just cant see how that happens.

I may have made en error or missed something when taking the fractions out of the Variance.

Answer (score 0):

In the image there are a few steps happening all at once and I suspect that there are two mistakes rolled into one step.

First, for any random variable $X$ it holds that
$$
\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(X + c)
$$
for any fixed $c \in \mathbb{R}$. This is shown by the following calculation
\begin{align}
    \text{Var}(X+c) &= \text{Var}(Y) \\ 
    &= \mathbb{E} \left [ ((X+c) - \mathbb{E}[X+c])^2 \right ] \\
    &= \mathbb{E} \left [ ( X + c- c  - \mathbb{E}[X])^2 \right ] \\
   &= \mathbb{E} \left [ ( X - \mathbb{E}[X])^2 \right ] \\
   &= \text{Var}(X)
\end{align}
Now letting $X = \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$ and $c = \frac{50}{N}$ this shows
$$
    \text{Var} \left (\frac{50}{N} + \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \right ) = \text{Var}(X + c) = \text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}\left ( \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \right ).
$$
Second, For any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and any random variable $X$ it holds
$$\text{Var}(aX) = a^2\text{Var}(X)$$ and this can also be shown using the formula for variance, similarly to what was done above. Now let $a = \frac{1}{2N}$ and $X = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$, then
$$
\text{Var}\left ( \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \right ) = \text{Var}(aX) = a^2\text{Var}(X) = \frac{1}{4N^2}\text{Var}\left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \right).
$$
I think that this may have been a small algebra mistake (happens to everyone!) since you squared the $N$ but not the 2.

After this use that the Variance of independent random variables is additive to see
$$\frac{1}{4N^2}\text{Var}\left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \right) = \frac{1}{4N^2} \sum_{i=1}^N \text{Var}(x_i).$$

Putting all the pieces together and simplifying we arrive at
$$
\text{Var} \left (\frac{50}{N} + \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \right ) = \frac{1}{4N^2} \sum_{i=1}^N \text{Var}(x_i) = \frac{1}{4N^2}(N \sigma^2) = \frac{\sigma^2}{4N}
$$
where I'm using the fact that $\text{Var}(x_i) = \sigma^2$ and there are $N$ of these terms in the last summation. After that it's just more algebra.

To test your knowledge, I recommend proving for yourself that $\text{Var}(aX) = a^2\text{Var}(X)$ using only the definition of variance and simple properties of expectation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough clarification, helped a lot!